# Building software on Arch and finding the dependency

Tags: arch-linux, make, c

I'm relatively new to compiling software. I downloaded a package called gr-scan which uses gnuradio and osmosdr (I have both installed and working via `pacman` already). [The instructions](http://www.techmeology.co.uk/gr-scan/) say to edit the `Makefile` and run `make`.

I checked the paths to gnuradio and osmosdr in the `Makefile` - they exist and have things in them - but the build returns this error;

```
In file included from main.cpp:23:0:
topblock.hpp:23:26: fatal error: gr_top_block.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:23: recipe for target 'gr-scan' failed
make: *** [gr-scan] Error 1
```

A quick Google shows `gr_top_block.h` is part of the [core gnuradio source](http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/repository/revisions/2bf64459036916258dcf3269cec47904fdeba8f6/entry/gnuradio-core/src/lib/runtime/gr_top_block.h) which I thought pacman would have kept somewhere? But when I search my drive with `find / -name "gr_top_block.h"` I get no results.

What's the next step? Should I download gnuradio and tell `make` where the source for it is somehow? Any advice appreciated

Comment: You need to download the source for gnuradio and update your include path as appropriate.

Comment: if it uses Makefiles for building, it is probably *incompatible* with the current version of GNU Radio; almost all out-of-tree GNU Radio modules use CMake nowadays.